# Oracle Trigger UPDATE instead of INSERT

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, oracle11g

Trying to find a way to write an Oracle trigger that would check before an insert to see if a match was found in the primary column and if so update the row information instead of inserting a new row.

I've looked at `before insert`. Is there a way to cancel the insert based on criteria inside that block?

I've also looked at using the `instead of` clause but it requires working on a view.

What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 4):

Use a MERGE statement instead of an INSERT.

Comment: Woudn't this be better as a comment than an answer?

Comment: If there is a way of doing what the OP asks then it does not represent a good solution to his problem, even if it's an accurate answer to the question.

Comment: well knowing that users will attempt to performa an insert is there a way to "catch" the insert and do an update instead?

Comment: As the OP says you could use an instead-of trigger on a view placed over the table. It's the only way I can think of, but I'm not sure if a mutating-table error might result. Or you could provide a PL/SQL api for the table instead of direct insert privileges, but in that case I'd implement a MERGE statement in it instead of checking to see if the row exists. There's a fundamental problem as well that the time that you check whether a row exists is different to the time at which you insert or update, so a row might be added or deleted in between the check and the insert/update.

Answer (score 0):

Use a merge statement.

```
MERGE INTO <<your table>> t
   USING (<<your list of records - can be the result of a SELECT >>)
   ON ( <<join between table and list of records >>)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET << the rows you want to set>>
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (<<columns of table>>)
  VALUES (<<value>>)
```

https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/merge-statement